# How to Use a Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: json, markdown, jupyter-notebook, visual-studio-2017

Visual Studio 2017 now supports use of a Jupyter Notebook.

[A Lap Around Python in Visual Studio 2017](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2017/05/12/a-lap-around-python-in-visual-studio-2017/#comment-253715)

According to the MSDN blog post:

> To work with a notebook, simply download your IPYNB file as a .py file and open it in Visual Studio. You’ll see that markdown cells have been turned into comments and each cell is collapsible and expandable.

When I download a IPYNB file, rename to a .py file, it displays in the VS editor as a JSON file containing markdown. I was expecting to see a markdown file. What am I missing?

Comment: In case you're looking to work with actual notebooks in something resembling Visual Studio, you can try Visual Studio Code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is what I believe they mean with the download as.
You need the Notebook running then click on File-> Download as-> **Pythong**(.py)

[image]

Once you have downloaded your Python file from the notebook you can open it in Visual Studio.

Edited: added the rest of the answer

Comment: No. Look at the image in the MSDN blog link. It clearly shows a notebook running in Visual Studio, not in Jupyter as shown in your link.

Comment: true but that is the way to download the IPYNB as a python file so you can import it to your visual studio solution

Comment: Indeed your answer solves a big part of the mystery. I'll soon respond with a bigger picture.

Answer (score 13):

@Jonathan answer is correct. The MSDN blog was referring to Jupyter Notebooks menu item `File->Download->Python (.py)`. There's additional considerations in getting a notebook to run and ultimately a issue with quality of experience.

1. To use a notebook in Visual Studio, download using Jupyter as stated above.
2. Specify the Python environment as Anaconda as shown in the blog image. To do so, either set Anaconda as the default environment or create a solution from existing files that specifies Anaconda as the environment.
3. Open a Python interactive window to display notebook execution.
4. Use Ctrl-Enter to step through notebook's statements.

That said, be aware that Visual Studio's notebook-ish experience is not at the level of Jupyter's, for now. Until VS directly integrates notebooks (.IPYNB files), I see little advantage of using VS over the real Jupyter.

1. VS has fewer and semantically different key bindings than Jupyter.
2. Jupyter's formatting (HTML) is far superior to VS (text).
3. There's little support and documentation for notebook-ish in VS.
4. The whole VS notebook-ish experience lacks polish.
5. IMHO, the beauty of Jupyter is the single window experience but VS uses two.

Answer (score 6):

As an alternative to Visual Studio that does not integrate well iPython notebooks, did you look at [PyCharms](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) that is a nice Python IDE (as far as I use it for now^^).

It provides a nice rendrering of ipython notebook inside the IDE making it a common IDE for python and iPython stuff. Maybe it worth a try.

Comment: You should mention that, with some exceptions, PyCharm is not freeware. It does have a debugger, a major feature, whereas Jupyter does not.

Comment: A new IDE alternative is JupyterLab which is free but doesn't have a debugger.

Comment: PyCharm has huge potential with its integrated Jupyter debugging (Visual Studio really needs to sort that out!) but check its matplotlib/seaborn charting delivers because currently the renderings a bit warped, hopefully fixed soon. At least VS does that fine.