# How connect to Jupyter notebook with Visual Studio 2017

Tags: python, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017, jupyter-notebook

Visual Studio Code has option to connect to jupyter notebook. When it's done I can execute my script by clicking shift+enter (or other shortcut) then there is jupyter notebook execution result in python interactive, eg. if I use matplotlib plot I can show this plot inside python interactive. I try to find same solution (integration with jupyter notebook) to Visual Studio 2017, according to my example I want to show my matplotlib plot in Visual Studio 2017 python interactive windo (which is connected to jupyter notebook I suppose). Is it possible? Is it correct approach?

I am not questioning how I can work with IPYNB file inside Visual Studio 2017, my question is rather how I can execute my python script as jupyter notebook execution?

If I have python script like [this](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/arctest.html#sphx-glr-gallery-lines-bars-and-markers-arctest-py)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
def f(t):
    'A damped exponential'
    s1 = np.cos(2 * np.pi * t)
    e1 = np.exp(-t)
    return s1 * e1

t1 = np.arange(0.0, 5.0, .2)

l = plt.plot(t1, f(t1), 'ro')
plt.setp(l, markersize=30)
plt.setp(l, markerfacecolor='C0')

plt.show()
```

and execute this script in Visual Studio Code with shift + Enter I have my result plot in python interactive window.
If I execute same script in Visual Studio 2017 with Debug->Execute File in Python Interactive then the result plot is outside python interactive window. Inside Visual Studio 2017 I use Anaconda 5.2.0 as Python Enviroment.
How to resolve this problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Use a Jupyter Notebook in Visual Studio 2017?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44057052/how-to-use-a-jupyter-notebook-in-visual-studio-2017)

Comment: Have you tried googling for `Visual Studio 2017 Jupyter`? The duplicate is the first result. It links to [A Lap Around Python in Visual Studio 2017](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/a-lap-around-python-in-visual-studio-2017/#comment-253715). Have you installed the Python payload in Visual Studio?

Comment: Yes, I have. Possible duplicate question is mainly about working with IPYNB file. However Lap Around Python does not resolve problem with plt. show inside anaconda interactive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/visualstudio/python/interactive-repl-ipython) tutorial I do some step to solve question problem. In Visual Studio 2017 Python Environments Window under Anaconda 5.2.0 enviroment I select Overview in dropdown list then I select Use IPython interactive mode checkbox and reset Python Interactive Window. Generally, the solution of the problem is to use IPython mode as described in quoted tutorial.

> The Visual Studio Interactive window in IPython mode is an advanced
>   yet user-friendly interactive development environment that has
>   Interactive Parallel Computing features.

Answer (score 1):

Try '%matplotlib inline'. That's what we use in the VS Code extension to force plots to show up in the interactive window.